# Display data from sqlite in Table layout,

Tags: android, xml, android-sqlite, android-tablelayout

i want to display my data from sqlite to my table which i create using tablelayout using xml, how i want to do that? is there any example? i do not know how to pass the value into table.. is it the same as we do listview or textview?

below is my xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:textColor="#fcfafa" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:text="@string/glucose"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#030303" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="500dp"
        android:layout_height="15dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
        android:background="#C4BFBF"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_width="28dp"
        android:layout_height="28dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/btn_home"
        android:onClick="onClickHome"
        android:src="@drawable/homebtn" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_marginRight="18dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:onClick="onClickAdd"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:text="@string/btn_add"/>

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/myTableLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="1dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton2"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="100dp" 
            android:background="@drawable/cell_normalshape">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:background="@drawable/cell_normalshape"
                android:layout_width="55dp"
                android:text="@string/date"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:textColor="#2A0A0A"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:background="@drawable/cell_normalshape"
                android:layout_weight="0.2"
                android:text="@string/Breakfast"
                android:layout_span="2"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#2A0A0A"
                android:textSize="16sp"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:background="@drawable/cell_normalshape"
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:textColor="#2A0A0A"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_span="2"
                android:text="@string/Lunch"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                android:background="@drawable/cell_normalshape"
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:textColor="#2A0A0A"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:layout_span="2"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/Dinner"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="100dp" 
            android:background="@drawable/cell_normalshape">

         <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView7"
                android:background="@drawable/cell_normalshape"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:textColor="#2A0A0A"
                android:text=""
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView8"
                android:background="@drawable/cell_normalshape"
                android:layout_weight="0.3"
                android:text="@string/Pre"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#2A0A0A"
                android:textSize="16sp"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView9"
                android:background="@drawable/cell_normalshape"
                android:layout_weight="0.3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#2A0A0A"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:text="@string/Post"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView10"
                android:background="@drawable/cell_normalshape"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:textColor="#2A0A0A"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:text="@string/Pre"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView11"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:textColor="#2A0A0A"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:text="@string/Post"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView12"
                android:background="@drawable/cell_normalshape"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:text="@string/Pre"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#2A0A0A"
                android:textSize="16sp"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView13"
                android:background="@drawable/cell_normalshape"
                android:text="@string/Post"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#2A0A0A"
                android:textSize="16sp"/>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="100dp" 
            android:background="@drawable/cell_normalshape">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView15"
                android:background="@drawable/cell_normalshape"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:textColor="#2A0A0A"
                android:text=""
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView16"
                android:background="@drawable/cell_normalshape"
                android:layout_weight="0.3"
                android:text=""
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#2A0A0A"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView17"
                android:background="@drawable/cell_normalshape"
                android:layout_weight="0.3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#2A0A0A"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:text=""
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView18"
                android:background="@drawable/cell_normalshape"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:textColor="#2A0A0A"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:text=""
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView19"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:textColor="#2A0A0A"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:text=""
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView20"
                android:background="@drawable/cell_normalshape"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:text=""
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#2A0A0A"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView21"
                android:background="@drawable/cell_normalshape"
                android:text=""
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#2A0A0A"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and here is my code..

```
private SQLiteDatabase database;
private ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>(); 
private ArrayList<Long> idList = new ArrayList<Long>();
private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.glucose_view);
    TableLayout myTable = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.myTableLayout);

    DBHelper helper = new DBHelper(this);
    database = helper.getWritableDatabase();

    // view data

    try{
        String query = "select * from " + DBHelper.TABLE_GLUCOSE;

        Cursor c = database.rawQuery(query, null);

        c.moveToFirst();
        c.moveToPosition(3);  // may be two, not sure if the cursor starts at 0 or 1
        while (c.isAfterLast() == false) {
            String tblName = c.getString(1);
            Cursor table = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + DBHelper.TABLE_GLUCOSE,null);
            table.moveToFirst();
            if (table.getString(table.getColumnIndex("Title")) != null) {
                //  Your code to create table
            }
            c.moveToNext();
        }
}
```

can anyone help me..

Comment: is you try with this code...what it gives..

Comment: is it the same as we do listview or textview? => Yes it's simple as we set value in TextView.

Comment: whats that mean? set value in textview?

Comment: can i use like this?  try{
   if( cursor != null ){
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
          do {
           idList.add(cursor.getInt(0));
        list.add(cursor.getString(1));} while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
   }
  }
  catch(SQLException e){ 
  }
     
  cursor.moveToFirst(); TextView TV_Name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TVName);TV_Name.setText(cursor.getString(1));cursor.close();

Comment: What is your problem, what do you want to achieve, why do you move your cursor to 4th record

Comment: thats just a sample code i try, i want to display the data from the sqlite, the data will be display in 7 columns, and dynamically add rows when new data insert

Comment: as i read, is it correct we just create table in the xml, the row we need to add in the java?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  if((cursor.moveToFirst())
      {
      do
       {
      LinearLayout layout=new LinearLayout(context);
      layout.setOrienation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
       for(int i=0;i<cursor.getColumnCount();i++)
        {
         TextView text=new TextView(context);
         switch(cursor.getType(i))      
         {
          case  Cursor.FIELD_TYPE_INTEGER:
           text.setText(String.valueOf(cursor.getInt(i)))
           break;
       case  Cursor.FIELD_TYPE_STRING:
           text.setText(cursor.getString(i))
           break;
...
..


          }
layout.addView(text);

        }
    tablelayout.addView(layout);
        }
        }whilie(cursor.moveToNext())
```

Comment: Declare a global variable context in your activity Content context; and set the context=this in onCreate, now use this context variable.  Context means scope

Comment: i'm really sorry, i just a beginner in this, this use with the xml code i create right? but how we want to declare the tablerows with the data we want to display?

Comment: press control and and then space after cursor it will show the available methods, http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getType%28int%29

Comment: it display, but not in the table that i create.. how i want to put such as column 1 in db in column1 in android table layout

Comment: @user2089567 I'll be back after 20 mins

Comment: i have 7 column per row, and in sqlite db i have 13 column, i just want to take 7 column that needed and put in the 7 column

Comment: You will probably have constants representing your columns, use cursor.getString(columnname)

Comment: getstring or getcolumnindex?

Comment: and may i asked, why did you the switch case?

Comment: No need to use that when you have a Column name and you know its type,  I have added that code because we need to get string  by using getString only, not possible to get them by using getInt, it will throw error, so to avoid that I have checked like that...

Comment: if(c!=null)
  {
   c.moveToFirst();
   int getDateIndex = c.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.GLUCOSE_DATE);
   
   if((c.moveToFirst()))
   {
    do
    {
       LinearLayout layout=new LinearLayout(context);
       layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
       for(int i=1;i<c.getColumnCount();i++)
       {
         TextView text = new TextView(context);
         text.setText(c.getString(getDateIndex));
         layout.addView(text);
       }
        myTable.addView(layout);
     }while(c.moveToNext());
   }
  }

Comment: i use like this, then all column print out the same data, i know its wrong, but i dont have the idea how to take one data one column

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25761/discussion-between-pragnani-and-user2089567)